# How to qunit test function tied to event being fired

Tags: qunit

js file

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('example').addEventListener('mousedown', myFunction, false);
};

function myFunction(e) {
    x = e.clientX-parseInt(document.getElementById('example').offsetLeft);
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', anotherFunction, true);
}
```

Trying to figure out how to test with QUnit. the page doesn't use jQuery, just straight JavaScsript. As you can see, onload includes an eventlistener being added to an element, and when that mouse event is fired, the myFunction function is called. qunit code please.

Comment: Are you trying to test whether or not the function is fired when the event occurs or are you trying to test the function itself?

Comment: Thanks for asking! I want to ensure I'm meeting code coverage for the function, but the function doesn't return anything so I'm assuming the event would need to be triggered

Answer (score 0):

In my mind this should be two tests:

One: you want to test to make sure the event listener is attached correctly.  For this you can just override `myFunction` (or use a spy like from [sinon](http://sinonjs.com)).  Then trigger a mouse click (see [MDN for triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)).

Then for the next function, do the same only attach the spy or override `anotherFunction`, and then just call your method directly.

** EDIT FOR INFO ABOUT SPIES **

If you've got sinon loaded, and myFunction is available in scope, you make myFunction a spy.

[From the docs for spies](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spies) and [event triggering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

```
test('callback', function(){
    sinon.spy(myFunction);
    // or
    var oldFunc = myFunction;
    myFunction = function(){
        ok(true, true, 'function called');
    }
    var event = new MouseEvent('down', {
        'view': window,
        'bubbles': true,
        'cancelable': true
     });

    // trigger event 
    document.getElementById('example').dispatchEvent(event);

    ok(myFunction.called, true, 'function called');
    myFunction.restore();
    //or
    myFunction = oldFunc;
});
```

Comment: @jsteinmann updated answer with a qunit example of how this might work using sinon to create a spy

Comment: cool.  i've never used sinon and i don't know if using the library will work in this case.  could you show a way to test overriding?

Comment: It should work -- sinon is a great tool for mocking purposes. However, example updated.

Comment: @jsteinmann I HIGHLY recommend using sinon for this though. it's what it is designed to do. There's even [an adapter for qunit](http://sinonjs.org/qunit/)

Comment: '[object MouseEventConstructor]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new MouseEvent('down', {
>>         'view': window,
>>         'bubbles': true,
>>         'cancelable': true
>>      })')
>> TypeError: '[object MouseEventConstructor]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new MouseEvent('down', {

Comment: @jsteinmann check out the MDN documentation for more help with that.

Comment: if the tests are run headless with phantomjs is this solution still correct?

Comment: called isn't defined, so how can i test an assertion against myFunction.called?  I'll just use sinon if you want to post the sinon only solution again.